# EOFError while using Pipe with multiprocessing in python

Tags: python, image-processing, multiprocessing, pipe

I'm trying to use the multiprocessing model to speed up the rate of detection for a model. I want to use four cores and process images in a parallel fashion while keeping them in order. When a process is spawned, a pipe is instantiated as well, the child portion is passed to the process while the parent is kept in a separate queue. The script throws an EOFError as I call the recv method on parent pipe even after I polled the pipe.

In a simpler version of this program, I simply sent "hello" instead of the image, but an EOFError was still thrown. Also, I tried the script with and without closing the child end of the pipe but the error was still thrown

```
import io 
import time
import tensorflow as tf
physical_devices = tf.config.experimental.list_physical_devices('GPU')
if len(physical_devices) > 0:
    tf.config.experimental.set_memory_growth(physical_devices[0], True)
from absl import app, flags, logging
import core.utils as utils
from core.yolov4 import filter_boxes
from tensorflow.python.saved_model import tag_constants
from PIL import Image
import cv2
import numpy as np
from tensorflow.compat.v1 import ConfigProto
from tensorflow.compat.v1 import InteractiveSession
from queue import Queue 
from concurrent.futures import ProcessPoolExecutor
from multiprocessing import Pool, Process, Pipe

flag_rep = {
    "framework" : 'tflite',
    "weights" : './checkpoints/yolov4-tiny-416.tflite',
    "size" : 416,
    "tiny" : False,
    "model" : 'yolov4',
    "iou" : .45,
    "score" : .25,
}
vid = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
config = ConfigProto()
config.gpu_options.allow_growth = True

session = InteractiveSession(config=config)
STRIDES, ANCHORS, NUM_CLASS, XYSCALE = utils.load_config_from_dict(flag_rep)
input_size = flag_rep['size']
interpreter = tf.lite.Interpreter(model_path=flag_rep['weights'])
interpreter.allocate_tensors()
input_details = interpreter.get_input_details()
output_details = interpreter.get_output_details()
i=0

def eval_im(frame, child):
    original_image = frame
    original_image = cv2.cvtColor(original_image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
    image_data = cv2.resize(original_image, (input_size, input_size))
    image_data = image_data / 255.
    images_data = []
    for i in range(1):
        images_data.append(image_data)
    images_data = np.asarray(images_data).astype(np.float32)
    interpreter.set_tensor(input_details[0]['index'], images_data)
    interpreter.invoke()
    pred = [interpreter.get_tensor(output_details[i]['index']) for i in range(len(output_details))]
    boxes, pred_conf = filter_boxes(pred[0], pred[1], score_threshold=0.25, input_shape=tf.constant([input_size, input_size]))
    boxes, scores, classes, valid_detections = tf.image.combined_non_max_suppression(
        boxes=tf.reshape(boxes, (tf.shape(boxes)[0], -1, 1, 4)),
        scores=tf.reshape(
            pred_conf, (tf.shape(pred_conf)[0], -1, tf.shape(pred_conf)[-1])),
        max_output_size_per_class=50,
        max_total_size=50,
        iou_threshold=flag_rep['iou'],
        score_threshold=flag_rep['score']
    )
    pred_bbox = [boxes.numpy(), scores.numpy(), classes.numpy(), valid_detections.numpy()]
    image = utils.draw_bbox(original_image, pred_bbox)

    child.send([img])
    child.close()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    processes = Queue()
    parent_pipes = Queue() 
    overflow = Queue()
    while True: 
        ret, pic = vid.read()
        overflow.put(pic)
        if processes.qsize() < 4: 
            parent, child = Pipe()
            parent_pipes.put(parent)
            process = Process(target=eval_im, args=(overflow.get(), child))
            processes.put(process)
            process.start()
        print(parent_pipes.qsize())
        if parent_pipes.queue[0].poll(): 
            process = processes.get()
            process.join()
            parent_pipe = parent_pipes.get()
            img = parent_pipe.recv()
            parent_pipe.close()
            
            # cv2.imshow("frame", img)
        if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
            break 
    vid.release()
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Here is the output:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "testing_multi.py", line 89, in <module>
    img = parent_pipe.recv()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/multiprocessing/connection.py", line 250, in recv
    buf = self._recv_bytes()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/multiprocessing/connection.py", line 407, in _recv_bytes
    buf = self._recv(4)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/multiprocessing/connection.py", line 383, in _recv
    raise EOFError
EOFError
```

Comment: Posting a simple example without all of these dependencies increases the chance you'll find people who can run it and test.

Comment: Can you make a minimal example that recreates the error without all the logic specific to your problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To anybody that stumbles across this now. I figured out that this error happens because of the Global interpreter lock in python. I'm not that well-read on it. But the gist is that only one thread at a time can use the python interpreter. Modules like concurrency and concurrent.futures can get around this by spawning multiple interpreters. However, then it is hard for data to be shared between the two instances. Thus there are tools like pipes and queues in some of these modules which allow these instances to communicate. However, these tools require that objects are "pickleable". In this case, my objects were not pickleable. Thus I got an error.